# How to use Callbacks with web3 and reactjs?

Tags: web3js

I have been having trouble with callbacks in reactjs with web3.  In the code below my alert function is properly printing the number of players returned by my contract but otherFuction is not being called and setState is not changing the value printed in my paragraph.

```
class PracticeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {players: ""};
  }

  componentWillMount(){

    simpleContract.methods.getPlayerNumber().call(function(error, result){
      alert(result);
      this.otherFunction(result);
    });

  }

  otherFunction(value){
    this.setState({
      players:value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <p> {this.state.players} <p/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

In previous attempts at a solution I have appended
    simpleContract.methods.getPlayerNumber().call() 
with 
    .then(this.otherfunction) 
but have not had luck.

Any thoughts?  Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context of `this` is lost by using the standard function declaration block. To fix, you have a few options:

(Recommended) Use arrow functions to keep `this` in reference:

```
componentWillMount(){
  simpleContract.methods.getPlayerNumber().call((error, result) => {
    alert(result);
    this.otherFunction(result);
  });
}
```

Chain bind `this` to the function declaration:

```
componentWillMount(){
  simpleContract.methods.getPlayerNumber().call(function(error, result){
    alert(result);
    this.otherFunction(result);
  }).bind(this);
}
```

Create a variable before the function declaration referencing `this`:

```
componentWillMount(){
  const _this = this;
  simpleContract.methods.getPlayerNumber().call(function(error, result){
    alert(result);
    _this.otherFunction(result);
  });
}
```

Comment: Fixed using method 1!  Thanks for your help and time!